# Python starting/stopping thread from another thread causes unexpected behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

After some research on how to properly ask a thread to stop, I am stuck into an unexpected behavior.

I am working on a personal project. My aim is to run a program on a RaspberryPi dedicated to domotics.

My code is structured as below:

1. a first thread is dedicated to scheduling : everyday at the same hour, I send a signal on GPIO output
2. a second thread is dedicated to monitoring keyboard for manual events
3. whenever a specific key is pressed, I want to start a new thread that is dedicated to another routine just like my first thread

Here is how I proceed:

```
import schedule
from pynput import keyboard
import threading

first_thread = threading.Thread(target=heating, name="heating")
second_thread = threading.Thread(target=keyboard, name="keyboard")
first_thread.start()
second_thread.start()
stop_event = threading.Event()
```

My heating routine is defined by:

```
def heating():
    def job():
        GPIO.output(4,GPIO.HIGH)
        return

    schedule.every().day.at("01:00").do(job)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

My keyboard monitor is defined as follow:

```
def keyboard():
    def on_press(key):
        if key == keyboard.Key.f4:
            shutter_thread = threading.Thread(name="shutter", target=shutter, args=(stop_event,))
            shutter_thread.start()
        if key == keyboard.Key.f5:
            stop_event.set()

     with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press,on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

My `shutter` thread target is similar to the heating one:

```
def shutter(stop_event):
    def open():
        GPIO.output(6,GPIO.HIGH)
        return

    t = threading.currentThread()

    schedule.every().day.at("22:00").do(open)
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Problem is everytime I press the key to start my `shutter` thread, the shutter routine is called but:

- the `job` within my `shutter` routine is executed twice
- the `job` within the first thread is also now executed twice every time it is on schedule !
- once I press the key to ask the `shutter` thread to stop, the `heating` (first) thread come back to its original (and correct) behaviour, but the `shutter` thread does not stop

I have no idea why starting this new thread yields such modification in the behaviour of the other thread. And why my stopping event is not working ?

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: This contains a least two references to non-standard libraries. Where are `schedule` and `keyboard` coming from? If  `schedule` is from [here](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), you are calling `run_pending()` twice from different threads, which seems a) wrong and b) racy.

Comment: You're right, I did forget to mention the libraries `schedule` from [here](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and `pynput` from [here](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) which provides the keyboard object. I did not realize calling `run_pending` twice would be wrong, thx ! This solves the first issue. But I still have an issue related to stopping my thread.

Comment: To be more specific about the remaining issue : if I remove the `schedule.run_pending()` instruction in the `shutter` function, how can I use my condition on the `stop_event` status to ask my thread to stop ? Maybe there is a better way to do so ? Checking for a clock instead of using schedule for example ?

Comment: @Beinje That is for the same reason, as you use two threading libraries, `threading` and `schedule`. In `shutter` you schedule the function and in `heating` *all* scheduled tasks are run (including the shutter task). You should rather unschedule that task by whatever means this library offers. See for example [here](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-can-i-cancel-several-jobs-at-once).

Comment: Thank you both for pointing me in the right direction. I now understand the problem. I finally create one scheduler object per thread. Thus I can properly use run_pending on these different schedulers, and use my threading event to stop the shutter thread. Should I write a proper answer to my question with credits to your comments ?

Comment: If you found a solution please feel free to add a corresponding answer. However I feel that a cleaner would be to use a single scheduler and then add and remove scheduled tasks as key press events occur. Because you are using the `schedule` framework for running your actual tasks it would be more natural to use this framework's API for stopping these tasks later on. [This function](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#schedule.Scheduler.cancel_job) let's you cancel running jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the `schedule` framework for managing tasks a clean solution would be to use the same framework's API for canceling jobs (instead of using `threading.Event`). That way tasks management remains within `schedule` and user interaction is handled by `threading`.

```
def keyboard():
    tasks = [] 

    def on_press(key):
        if key == keyboard.Key.f4:
            # Shutter task.
            tasks.append(
                schedule.every().day.at("22:00").do(lambda: GPIO.output(6,GPIO.HIGH))
            ) 
        if key == keyboard.Key.f5:
            schedule.cancel_job(tasks.pop(-1))

     with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press,on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()

# Heating task. 
schedule.every().day.at("01:00").do(lambda: GPIO.output(4,GPIO.HIGH))

# Start keyboard listener.
ui = threading.Thread(target=keyboard)
ui.start()

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if [a_guest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3767239/a-guest) solution is a clean one, I can share a second solution for those who can face a similar situation.

A working solution is to define a specific scheduler in the different threads instead of using the default one.

Illustration:

```
def heating():
    def job():
        GPIO.output(4,GPIO.HIGH)
        return

    heat_sched = schedule.Scheduler()
    heat_sched.every().day.at("01:00").do(job)

    while True:
        heat_sched.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)


def shutter(stop_event):
    def open():
        GPIO.output(6,GPIO.HIGH)
        return

    shutter_sched = schedule.Scheduler()
    shutter_sched.every().day.at("22:00").do(open)

    while True:
        if not stop_event.is_set():
            shutter_sched.run_pending()
            time.sleep(0.5)
        else:
            shutter_sched.clear()
            return
```